# Change Application Name in Sql Server Profiler

Tags: sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-profiler

When profiling a .Net Application in SQL Server Profiler the default Application Name is taken from the Data Provider. How can I change this to my own Application Name?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just add `Application Name=My Application;` to the Connectionstring

Example:
`connectionString="Server=mySqlServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User id=aUser;Password=aPassword;Application Name=My Application;"`

You can also use `App=My Application`

Comment: @MichealChoudhary I just tried this with SQL Server 2016 Developer and had no issues. The application name appeared in SQL Profiler.

Comment: Worked for me in SQL Server 2017 & Management studio 18

Comment: in a website asp.net webform fails The requested database does not have a valid ADO.NET provider name set in the connection string.

Comment: If I use `Application Name=`, then I get a message from the driver (Native Client 11, and ODBC 17)  telling me `Invalid connection string attribute`. However,  `APP=` seems to work in most cases? [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Valid content of the connection string is highly dependent on which Data Provider you use. Please have a look at, for example, https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for examples that you can use.