# Identify table or columns being populated through front end in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to locate tables and columns that are associated with the front end. Is there a way to identify these. If for example, I add a record through the front end is there a feature in SQL server that will help identify which table/s are being populated?

Any thoughts/guidance appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly. But you can use SQL Server Profiler to see the query involved. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: To the database, all clients are the same  - even SSMS or Visual Studio are just clients as far as the database is concerned. You can modify the connection string and [add an Application Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147192/change-application-name-in-sql-server-profiler) that will allow you to trace and filter the queries used by specific applications in SQL Server Profiler or the newer Extended Events profiler