# How to customize the SQL Server connection ApplicationName property in Nhibernate for profiling

Tags: nhibernate, connection-string, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to correlate SQL query activity in a SQL Server Studio profile trace with different client processes in a large application that I am new to. The connection ApplicationName column in the trace window is set to ".Net SQLClient Data Provider" for all profiled query activity.

I would like to override the ApplicationName property on each new NHibernate command or connection with more meaningful internal application names associated with the main processes of the large application.

I have set a custom ApplicationName before but is it possible with NHibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first method I found was to use the connection-string (see links), but that is per connection and not per command and you won't know when .Net/NHibernate/Connection-Pooling/... decides to make a new connection.

[Change Application Name in Sql Server Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147192/change-application-name-in-sql-server-profiler)

[https://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/#:~:text=Simply%20include%20%22Application%20Name%3DMyAppName,%2C%20%22SELECT%20APP_NAME()%3B%22](https://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Simply%20include%20%22Application%20Name%3DMyAppName,%2C%20%22SELECT%20APP_NAME()%3B%22).

I am trying to find an T-SQL-Command to change/set this value from within a connection, but wasn't lucky till now.

Greetings

Juy Juka